# power mac G5 won't boot past the logo - shuts down to a black screen

Tags: macos, g5

I think the HD is full? When I power up it chimes and I get the logo screen and whirling ball then after a 20 seconds it shuts down to a black screen and powers off. I tried to start in Safe Start Mode but no go.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the Install Disc 1 DVD to start the Apple Hardware Test that came with your computer into the cd drive. Holding down C as soon as the computer boots.